# SQLite Update and bool results

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, boolean, sql-insert

I found some tutorial about creating local SQL databases.

I need to update a value of my database or insert it in the table if it does not already exists.

I thought I could use a IF statement and bool property of "update".

```
public void onClick(View view) {

if (view == play) {

//Here I am trying to update position one with the value of (int) test

   boolean uc = myDb.AggiornaStato("1",test);

//If the field is empty bool should be false, right?

    if (uc == false) {

//so .. insert that value 

        myDb.CreaStato(test);


    }

//next time, update should be true, and It won't create another ID

startService(new Intent(this, t1.class));

}
```

I'd have to manage seven IDs so I will create different methods for each ID and each Row. I know this is not the right way, but I could not find something that would fit to my needs. When the app starts it creates empty Database and Tables so the first time I need to insert values, but then I need just to update and I thought I could use "If then else" but I am messing somewhere!

This is what I have in databaseHelper class to create (CreaStato) or update (Aggiorna Stato)

```
 public boolean CreaStato(int stato) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_6, stato);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }



    public boolean AggiornaStato (String id, int stato) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, stato);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] { id });
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: `I need to update a value of my database or insert it in the table if it does not already exists.` Simply use a `REPLACE INTO` instead of an `INSERT INTO` SQL command. In your case: `db.replace()`.

Comment: This comment is kind of unrelated but have you looked into Realm. https://realm.io/ This is fast and really easy to use database tool for all platforms including android. It's super easy to implement and for beginners like you, it's perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much Rotwang! :-) It worked! I had to change something to made It work properly. I removed "autoincrement" and added the ID to the "replace" method!

Answer (score 0):

Your `AggiornaStato()` function always returns `true`.

The [update() function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) returns the number of rows that actually were updated, so you have to check that:

```java
public boolean AggiornaStato (String id, int stato) {
    ...
    int rows = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{ id });
    return rows > 0;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    ...
    boolean updated = myDb.AggiornaStato("1", test);
    if (!updated)
        myDb.CreaStato(test);
    ...
}
```

(And it would be a good idea to replace [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) with [insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)).)